# Configure IIS 7.5 website to never shut down

Tags: iis-7.5

I'm configuring IIS 7.5 website hosting several web services to never-shut-down. I understand that there is a setting in applicationHost.config to enable this

```
<applicationPools>
  <add name="AppPoolName" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
  ...
</applicationPools>
```

However, I would like configure this in IIS Manager user interface, e.g. as an advanced setting of the application pool. Is there such a setting somewheere in IIS Manager?

**EDIT:**

I found [another possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596267/how-to-disable-the-application-pool-idle-time-out-in-iis7) which led me [here](http://brad.kingsleyblog.com/IIS7-Application-Pool-Idle-Time-out-Settings/):

> If you want to extend the length of the time-out setting, just change
>   it from the default of 20 to however many minutes you want. You can
>   also adjust the setting to 0 (zero) which effectively disables the
>   timeout so that the application pool will never shut down due to being
>   idle.

However, I would like to know if I can set `startMode="AlwaysRunning"` in GUI.

Answer (score 5):

In IIS 7.5+, it is possible to do this through the GUI. Right click on the Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> General -> Start Mode. Change that to "Always running" and it should accomplish what you are looking for.

Have a look at below screenshot:

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A web service or website never really get shutdown. The only thing that will get shut down or recycled is the application pool. If you don't want the application pool to do that, you can set the advance property of the application pool in your IIS Manager.

Comment: Ok, to be precise, [worker process is shut down after 20 minutes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx). Your answer is "you can set the advance property of the application pool in your IIS Manager". Read my question carefully, it was "which property?".

Comment: Once you're in Advanced Settings, go to Process Model-> Idle Time-out  set that to 0